# Ignoring the first element of xml node collection when looping with xslt

Tags: xslt

i am looping through an xml doucment with xslt for each
i need to ignore the first element and consider the rest when looping.

could somebody help me on this.
i am new to xslt.

thanking you.
Ramana kumar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="...your xpath...">
    <xsl:if test="position()!=1"> <!-- ignore first node -->
        ..code here...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```